# Let parallaxscrolling be dashy

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Oh yes, I *am* going to meta-post about a *one-punctuation-character-difference*, because this is about *dashes* and I *love* dashes.

[parallaxscrolling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallaxscrolling) has 34 questions — [parallax-scrolling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallax-scrolling) none. All of our other multi-word tags ([collision-detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection), [opengl-es](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl-es), ...) are dashes-between-words.

I think non-dashy infidels should be forcibly converted to dashyness. Do the mods wield almighty power to convert masses—or should we retag these the old-fashioned way?

[image: dashy mod hat] [image: dashy sword]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [parallax-scrolling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallax-scrolling) didn't exist before. It does now. And, [parallaxscrolling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallaxscrolling) has been merged into it, so anyone trying to use that non-dash-non-sense will be converted to the dash-tastic [parallax-scrolling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallax-scrolling).